# What is "Empty Trash" option in shared partition

Tags: pantheon-files

I am using elementary OS freya *0.3.2*.

[image: Imgur]

As shown in the screenshot, I have a common partition (`data` in ntfs) for all my OSes.When I right-click on the partition, it has `Empty Trash` option, which is not available for remaining partitions. Why?

Also, when I click on that option, some files are added to Trash which are not listed via terminal in `~/.local/share/Trash`